# Intended way of making content fit to screen size of device in MAUI

Tags: xaml, maui

In the MAUI framework, what is considered best practice/the intended way of making content fill the screen of the running device?

As for the content, let's assume it's a BoxView, for simplicity.

I've made a small example here. Disregard the space between the screen and the content:

[image: Sketch of the view, with borders.]

Regardless of what device is running the app, what kind of layout is best? Grid, StackLayout, etc...

Comment: I use grid for this. How optimal it is? I do not care. When I get into performance issue, Ill start think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Regardless of what device is running the app, what kind of layout is best? Grid, StackLayout, etc...

I think it depends on the specific situation. Each layout has its own characteristics. For more details you can refer to the official doc: [Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/?view=net-maui-7.0).